# templating system with zf2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, php

we are planing to create a CMS with zf2 and doctrine orm .

actually we are concern about our cms templating 
we want our system works with several templates and easily change between themes via admin

and creating a new templates should be easy for end-users developers

we want an advice or suggest for how to build templating system that :

there is a core module and there a lot sub modules with their own phtml 
so where to store theme1 phtml and where to store theme2 phtmls ...

any suggest or advice please
thanks

Comment: Do not create your own templating engine, you will regret it sooner or later. Use Twig as suggested below if you want very comprehensive templates.

Comment: read my comments in first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you activate another module in the application.config.php which has the same views and layouts (same folder structure and filenames) it's viewscripts and layouts will automatically be used when it's loaded after your core module.

so you could simply make your application.config.php dynamic to load the active template module which only contains the view folder. this would be a simple and effective solution without any other libraries.

additionally you can use an asset manager like assetic to also provide images, css etc. inside of your (template-)modules. (have a look at zf2-assetic-module, I wrote my own assetize-module based on assetic to fit my needs...)

Comment: read previous answer to get what i mean about multiple themes

Comment: no each module would have one single theme, the modules could be named like ThemeBlue, ThemeGreen etc...

Comment: you mean use themes as modules?

Comment: thank you very much ... i think your solution will works ... but please update your answer with code snippet that guide me to make themeblue module (for ex.) override other's phtml file

Answer (score 3):

I encourage you to take a look at [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), its the best template engine I have seen so far :) It does take some time to learn Twig syntax, but its well worthy if you look at what you get :)

I cant yet write comments, so I wrote this as an answare.
Hope this helps. Trust me, the Twig is the way to go. Joust look at his documentation for more specific details how to use it!

EDIT:

The problem you are trying to solve has nothing to do with template engine. You can do that with any template engine. You can do it even with plain PHP if you want.

I built web application where users can register, get their own sub domain, and there they can build their webpage. Change theme, edit text, add pages. Simple CMS functionality.

The easiest way to do this is to have themes folder, where you would store themes, like  this:

```
themes/
    - themeBlue
        - css/
        - images/
        - js/
        - html or views/

    - themeRose
        ...
```

Now this is where you would place all your themes, every theme has its own folder with images, css, js files...

And then you would have users, and every user would be able to choose and change theme.
That information would be stored in database. You need to store that user Jack is using themeBlue. You can do that as you want. You can event put this in users table like user_theme column.

Now when someone visits site, you first query database to see what theme is that user or creator of web using. And then you load all that files from current theme folder. And populate html files with data stored in database like in any other CMS.

This is the simplest implementation. You could for example, store css and html files in database :)

Hope this answers your question.
Good luck with that, I almost gone mad building my system :) I ended up with writing my own PHP MVC Framework joust to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: i saw twig .. and saw zf2 twig module ...  i want to know how to make twig now load template file for theme1 or theme2 or theme3 ... you understand what i mean?

Comment: No. What would be a theme? CSS file? Or you are building a CMS where user would be able to build his site, and then change themes? And every theme would have different HTML/CSS files?

Comment: exactly ... changing themes with different html/css/images files ... my question is about file structure and code structure of themes/twigfiles/cssfiles/... for cms themes

Comment: Il write this in original answer, its to long to explain here.

Comment: thank u for your answer ... but i already now that approach ... my question is how make zf2 load themeblue or load themerose ! .. you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Sina,

I do this in my Application->Module.php onBootstrap

```
    $ss = $serviceManager->get('application_settings_service');
    $settings = $ss->loadSettings();

    $serviceManager->get('translator');
    $templatePathResolver = $serviceManager->get('Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack'); 
    $templatePathResolver->setPaths(array(__DIR__ . '/view/'.$settings['theme'])); // here is your skin name 

    $viewModel = $application->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->themeurl = 'theme/'.$settings['theme'].'/';
```

In this situation I have this structure in my view folder

```
    view/
       default/
          application/
          error/
          layout/
          zfcuser/
       red/
          application/
          error/
          layout/
          zfcuser/
```

The $viewmodel above injects a variable into the layout for the themeurl in the public_html folder /theme/red/  with all assets for red

Access in layout.phtml -> themeurl;?>  in a viewscript layout()->themeurl;?>

I am still working out my Dynamic Views. Right now I have a BaseController and all my ActionControllers extend it. It has a render() function that builds the required views but not sure its going to be scalable hoping to try some placeholder ideas.

application_settings_service is a Settings Service that gets settings for whatever domain was used to call the system and builds an array accessible via any service aware part of the site. Thats a whole different post and it may or may not rub MVC peeps the wrong way

I know your question is marked answered just thought I would share

Eric